# Can't find .NET as a version in Azure App Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, .net-5, azure-appservice

I migrated my app locally from 3.1 to version 5. I deployed it but I get the following error:

> HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies
> Common solutions to this issue:
> The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.
> Specific error detected by ANCM:
> Error: An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServices.HostingStartup.deps.json) was not found: package: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServices.HostingStartup', version: '5.0.0-preview.3.20215.14' path: 'lib/netcoreapp5.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServices.HostingStartup.dll'
> Troubleshooting steps:
> Check the system event log for error messages
> Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
> Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect

I did some research and found that I need to update my App Service as well but I can't find .NET 5 as a listing in my App Service. This is what the dropdown looks like:

[image]

I added `ASP.NET Core 5.0 (x64) Runtime` (because the platform is 32 bits) as an Extension as well but I kept getting the same error. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Use .NET 6. There's no .NET 5 any more. That was a short-term version that went out of support last week. That wasn't a sudden change either, the .NET (Core) lifecycle policies were announced *several* years ago. There are Long-Term-Support versions that are supported for 2 years (2.1, 3.1, 6) and short-term versions that are released in the meantime and are only supported for 1 year

Comment: The .NET (Core) lifecycle policy is explained in [.NET and .NET Core Support Policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core). Most likely, you won't have to do anything to run on .NET 6. In  your project you may only have to change the target from `net5.0` to `net6.0` and upgrade packages